# Find specific static file in URL using js Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I find if an URL has a file like this in its structure using regex?

http://domain.com/file.xxx
http://domain.com/.../file.xxx

Where file.xxx could be ( .css / .js / .jpg ) etc ?

Something like:

```
var staticURL = url.match(//) // verify if it matches
```

We suppose url is a function parameter.

Comment: You want file type or file name?

Comment: Is there a difference if you verify this using regex ? I would like to have a regex for this if possible

Comment: I meant using regex only, do you want to extract file name or want to have a check that (.css/.js/.jpg) file type should be there

Comment: I want to check that those types should be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var regex = /\.(css|js|jpg)$/i;
var staticURL = regex.test(url);
```

That will find a URL ending in .css, or .js, or .jpg, and it will ignore case sensitivity.

Comment: Thank you. What is `test` ? Can you use `url.match` instead of `var regex` ?

Comment: `test()` is a method of RegExp objects documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test). `match()` is a method of String objects that returns either an Array of the matches, or `null` if there is no match (documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)).

Comment: I got it. What if I want to check if the url is only ending with a backslash `/` ?

Comment: I'd use a regex like this: `/\/$/`. That's an escaped forward slash (`\/`), followed by a dollar sign—which matches the end of a string.

Comment: @Allen nice one. And if I want to add this condition along with finding a `.html or .htm` file ? How would I do this ? So if a URL ends with backslash or .htm / .html. This is my last question

Comment: This is one option: `/\.?(htm|html|\/)$/`. The question mark makes the literal period optional. There are many ways to write these kinds of regular expressions. You might consider reading [this whole page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: I noticed something. When I test this on regex101, it only return me the extension. How can I be able to see the name of the file of that extension ?